# Are there any step-down regulators without capacitors for a vacuum environment?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, dc, step-down

I'm trying to find step-down DC-DC regulators that would take input voltages of ~30V and convert it to 5V and ~24V.

I was originally looking at linear regulators such as the [7805T](https://www.futurlec.com/Linear/7805T.shtml), but the specific project I am working on would need to perform in a vacuum environment. As far as I understand, electrolytic capacitors cannot work in space as they have a high probability of popping due to the vacuum environment. Since the 7805T linear regulator and many other regulators require capacitors in order to function properly, I need to find an alternative option for a step-down regulator.

I searched online, but it appears to be that the vast majority of these voltage step-down regulators/converters require capacitors in one form or another. From [breakout transformers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08L5VRBZS) to linear regulators, it appears that I can't find any without capacitor(s).

Is there a DC-DC step-down voltage regulator out there that does not use capacitor(s) in any way?

I also found [a line of regulators from Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/category/209/d24v5fx-step-down-voltage-regulators) that are quite small, but I'm unable to determine whether it has a capacitor (there is something that appears as one on the boards of these, but I'm unable to tell whether it's a capacitor or not).

Comment: are there no vacuum compatible capacitors?

Comment: You can probably use solid tantalum or ceramic capacitors.  They won't pop in a vacuum.

Comment: Is this going to space, or is it running in a bell jar?  heat is a big problem for vacuum electroncs.

Comment: **Aluminum electrolytic** capacitors aren't vacuum compatible -- the "electrolytic" in the name is actually a water-based goo.  But there are capacitors that work in space.  Possibly even wet-slug tantalums, if you shop for them carefully.  But there's enough consumer-grade caps that'll work that it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Any regulator is going to require capacitors. How large a capacitor will depend on the design. But know that there are plenty of reasons to avoid linear regulators--in particular, they produce a lot of heat, especially when stepping down 30 V to 5 V. That itself will be very difficult in a vacuum, as there's no airflow to take heat away; you have to use radiative cooling alone.

Comment: What will you use the regulated voltages for, and what is the power source?

Comment: Thanks for the responses;
So what would be a standard brand/type for one of these capacitors that work in space?

Comment: @Runsva I worked for a short time around silicon on sapphire: UHV at about 10 nanoPascals. Near Auger electron study levels. Near Earth the outgassing from Earth gives maybe a microPascal or so to maybe 100 microPascals, depending. But interplanetary? That's more like 10 femptoPascals. So is this for space? If so, have you taken time to search the nasa.gov or science.gov sites? It may be worth the time.

Comment: This would be a for a student project that would be in space for a certain amount of time, yes. I was just wondering whether there was an established brand or type of these capacitors that's really popular in the space industry, as I'm not familliar with them at all.

Comment: @Runsva You could start [here](https://www.kyocera-avx.com/products/tantalum/high-reliability/space-level/). But if this is a student project, have you been provided with contacts to help you through the design process? (Also note that high energy particles are ... annoying. See [2016 Summer Series - Jin-Woo Han: Vacuum Electronics in a Nanometer Era](https://images.nasa.gov/details/ARC-20160607-AAV2843-SummerSeries-01-JinWooHan-Youtube) for an idea of just how annoying they are for FETs, for example.)

Comment: Not really, this is more of a club project. Not directly supervised by anyone, hence why I'm searching for sources online. It's tricky, because a lot of the terminology in these datasheets is really unfamilliar to me, I don't really know what I'm looking for. I've only ever searched for capacitance when it came to acquiring capacitors, this is more complicated. There's over 500 different capacitor types on that website you sent, I've already looked through their catalog. I'm kinda lost as to what to look for...

Comment: @Runsva Start with specifications, I guess. How long does this have to work? What's the expected vacuum level? What outgassing is allowable and for how long? (Even high quality steels will outgas.) What kind of energetic particle events are there? And how often? Can you tolerate latch-up? Or soft events that self-recover, but cause trouble anyway? What's the thermal environment? What's your own device's expected dissipation and how will that be removed? What kind of 'crud' will be created nearby and land on your stuff? There's a lot of education involved, I suspect. Write to someone. May help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it. Someone has actually reccomended to me to use the ceramic layered capacitors. Would something like this work?: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07QGDGGZV

Answer (score 4):

You cannot avoid using capacitors in any kind of real electronics design.  Fortunately, people have been figuring out how to make electronics work in vacuum since at least the 1950's, as demonstrated by Sputnik, thousands of other satellites, and innumerable terrestrial applications in vacuum chambers or vacuum flasks.

Simply don't use aluminum electrolytics or other capacitors that aren't suitable for vacuum use, and be sure to choose chips that will function with the capacitors that you can economically use.  Even in the 1970's, when the 7805 was introduced, one could, with digging, find suitable capacitors that will work in a vacuum.  If the size and cost of the capacitors you find is objectionable, do some combination of shopping harder and finding circuits that don't need as much capacitance.

Suitable candidates *that I know of* at this moment are:

- Solid-electrolyte tantalum or niobium capacitors.
- Multi-layer ceramic chip capacitors.
- (Possibly, and it'll be expensive) wet-slug tantalum, but double-check -- you want the ones that come in hermetically sealed packages.

Comment: There are some solid aluminum capacitors, called aluminum polymer capacitors, that might be suitable, but do research them first--I've never worried about vacuum-suitability so I don't know. I expect most film capacitors would work as well, but they would probably cost more in terms of size, weight, and money than any of the other options.

Comment: I'd be a bit worried about a film cap outgassing.  Plastics can have all sorts of unexpected volatiles trapped inside them that come out and either leave behind unsuitable plastic, or that settle on their surroundings to the detriment of, well, everything.  Of course, that's the case for just about _anything_ that you want to work in an environment where pressure is measured in single-digit Pascals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply;
So would a solid tantalum capacitor like this work:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/T110A474K035AT/12502223?utm_adgroup=General&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax:%20Smart%20Shopping_Product_Zombie%20SKUS&utm_term=&utm_content=General&gclid=Cj0KCQiAi8KfBhCuARIsADp-A56WBZdqJ1ho4sFBhYrGWcTdUZLEFDbmuGTeWm2joqpoaZpl_yxqu0MaAjVBEALw_wcB

Comment: The data sheet says nothing about working in a vacuum or high altitude.  It does, however, say they're qualified to MIL–PRF–39003.  Perhaps you could download that standard and look at what it says.

Comment: Note that you've chosen a wet-slug tantalum -- that's inherently not as safe as a ceramic or solid-electrolyte tantalum, but as long as that hermitically sealed package stays that way, it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, would something like this work: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07QGDGGZV